# JQuery function call with out an event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose i have below jq function,

```
$(document).ready( 
  function(){ $('#demo_btn').click( 
         function(){ $.popup.show("The title", "A nice message"); 
  } ); 
});
```

I need to call the above function with out a click event. For example suppose a i check a condition and if its > than 10 im showing the above message. So its like no click event but just calling the above function when a condition satisfy after the page load.

More details its like im set a value for a variable in the controller and from view tpl im acccess it. So if the variable is >10 im showing the above alert. So if the variable is >10 the above alert should be display with out a click on a buton.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

```
<?php if ($var > 10) { ?>
    $('#demo_btn').trigger('click');
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in javascript if it satisfies the above condition then  call the popup function.

if you can post the whole code then it will be easy to suggest an exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, you can do something like this:

```
$('#demo_btn').click(doStuff);

function doStuff() {
   $.popup.show("The title", "A nice message");
}
```

You can then call the `doStuff` function as normal anywhere else in your code.

**Update...** Having reread your question, I think you might actually be looking for something that is constantly checking to see if a variable has a certain value. If that's the case, you can use `setInterval`:

```
var x = 1;

setInterval(doStuff, 500);

function doStuff() {
    if(x > 10) {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

The above code checks the value of `x` to see if it's greater than 10 every 500 milliseconds. Here's an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tv5JL/) showing the above concept in action.

Comment: the first part works, but pollutes the global namespace. the second one, again, works, but unnecessary triggers the timer...

Answer (score 0):

when you are using a php, you can use it like below

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  <?php if($variable>=10){?>
 $.popup.show("The title", "A nice message"); 
 <?php }?>
}); 
</script>
```